# Animation delay for this snippet?

Tags: jquery, delay

I read up on jQuery delaying, but I can't seem to delay my animation for this `mouseover` call:

```
$("div#test").mouseover(function ()
{
    $("div#test").delay(1000).animate({width:100}, {queue:false});  
    $("div#test").delay(1000).animate({height:100}, {queue:false});
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are the delays not working at all or are they both just starting at the same time?

Comment: What were you trying to do with `{queue:false}` anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `queue: false` boolean, which has the effect of starting the animation immediately (from the API page for `animate()`):

> `queue`: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If `false`, the animation will begin immediately.

Removing that, and combining effects into one `animate()` call seems to make things work as expected:

```
$("div#test").mouseover(function ()
{
    $(this)
        .delay(1000)
        .animate({width:100, height: 100});
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9DKYZ/).

References:

- [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
- [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).